# Changing MongoDB repl to shard, when should I restart my apps?

Tags: mongodb

I need to change my MongoDB repl  to sharded cluster, as the document says:

my current rs is rs0, and a new rs1.

1. run mongo-config server.
2. run mongos
3. connect to mongos
4. add shard (rs0)
5. add shard (rs1)
6. enableSharding(database)
7. create index of shared keys for the will-sharded collections
8. enableSharding(collection)

My question is, after which step, should I restart my apps to let apps connect to mongos but the rs0?

Comment: You seem to be trying to avoid any downtime, and that is not going to happen. Bottom line is your application(s) is going to have to stop before you bring a single shard on-line. Once an active replica-set becomes part of a sharded cluster you don't want anything writing to it other than through the `mongos` router. Your app should be down as soon as you begin adding shards, and ideally until all chunk migrations are complete.

Comment: I'd probably do it differently anyway: build up the sharded environment with rs1, in parallel Id create the index needed for sharding *in background*. Then, the *necessary* downtime would be reduced to the time you need to add rs1 to the sharded cluster and shard the collection.